# cocos2d-x Convert nsstring to char*

Tags: cocos2d-x

```
NSString *_str=@"rank";
const char *color_char1 = [_str cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I run it in iphone 6.0 Simulator, it works fine; but when I run it on new iPad it crashes.

I can't get `color_char1` ,why?

Comment: Weird thing..you sure it crash on this line?

Answer (score 2):

const char * myChar = [@"hey I am an NSString" UTF8String];

That should work :D

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
NSString *_str=@"rank";

const char *color_char1 = (char *)_str;
```